# .NET WebBrowser control with good performance and automatic NTLM authentication

Tags: webbrowser-control, geckofx, awesomium, webkit.net

For our project we need .NET WebBrowser control that supports automatic Windows authentication (like IE does). We have reviewed a number of options, but still can't select proper one:

1) Standard WebBrowser control based on IE. Quite fast, but it just has enormous memory leaks. On our rich-script page each opening of new page leaks about 7Mb of memory. There are a lot of discussions around it, but no solution.

2) Awesomium WebBrowser control (awesomium.com). It looked as really good option and in documentation was stated that it supported automatic windows authentication, so we were going to buy it. But automatic windows authentication just doesn't work. Support simply ignores all questions about it (although answers other ones quite quickly). That was one of the worst support of paid components that I have seen.

3) GeckoFx - it works quite well, but it is too slow (even IE control in 2-3 times faster).

4) Webkit.Net - it is very fast and it would have been good choice, but it doesn't support automatic windows authentication at all.

Are there any other choices that we can consider? Both free/paid components work for us.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried a version of geckofx that uses a newer firefox? eg. https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-9.0/downloads